# Getting information from keyboard in SciTE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scite

I am reading a book about ruby, it learn me that I write my program in
SciTE and then use F5 in keyboard to run my program.
Now , today I write this very very simple program :

a = gets.chomp!

when I write this code in Interactive Ruby enviroment , this code runs
as I want but when I write this code in SciTE and use F5 after some
seconds a black window opens and I can't write anything and I can't use
"gets" instruction in my program.
please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like your subsystem was set to something other than console.

Try adding this line to SciTEGlobal.properties:
command.go.subsystem.$(file.patterns.rb)=console

Also, to stop the process from running, press CTRL+Break